# Having some problem with reading JSON file

Tags: java, json, javafx

I have a JSON file which contains a dictionary (an actual English to Persian dictionary) and I wrote a java Class to read it and it doesnt work
i wrote a function which i use in to read a particular part of the file.

This is my reader Class :

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JSONReader {
    static JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    static JSONArray dictarray;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException, IOException {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Mohsen\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DSFP2\\dictionary.JSON"));
        JSONArray dictarray = (JSONArray)obj;
    }

    public void read() {
        System.out.println(dictarray.get(0));
    }
}
```

this is the FXMLController file which makes a new object of this class and tries to use it:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    JSONReader JR = new JSONReader();

    @FXML
    private void action (KeyEvent event) {
        JR.read();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    

}
```

And this is the error i get:

```
Executing C:\Users\Mohsen\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DSFP2\dist\run1082927040\DSFP2.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre/bin/java
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1770)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1653)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3965)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3911)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2502)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:147)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$349(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$195/1857609670.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:227)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:956)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1963387170.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at JSONReader.read(JSONReader.java:17)
    at FXMLDocumentController.action(FXMLDocumentController.java:11)
    ... 41 more
```

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the file in the `main` method of the `JSONReader` class, which is never executed as this is not the main class of the application.

Put that code into the `read` method:

```
public class JSONReader {
    JSONArray dictarray;

    public void read()  throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException, IOException {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Mohsen\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DSFP2\\dictionary.JSON"));
        dictarray = (JSONArray)obj;
    }
}
```

**Edit 01.01.2020:**

To only read the file once, move that code into a separate method - I named it `init`, and call that once, you could also put it in a constructor. Then in the `read` method you cann access the data you read i previously.

```
public class JSONReader {
    static JSONArray dictarray;

    public void init()  throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException, IOException {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Mohsen\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DSFP2\\dictionary.JSON"));
        dictarray = (JSONArray)obj;
    }

    public Object read() {
      return dictarray.get(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: But in this solution, every time i want to read from the file i have to open it! I was trying to write in a way that only 1 opening would be enough! But tnQ anyways!

Comment: @MohsenAmiriAmjad Why do you need to do you need multiple instances of the `JSONReader` class? If your program is properly designed, you should be able to share the data between the parts of the code that require access. If you insist on using `static` data (which is bad practice), you could still move the file reading to a `static` initializer block or use a singleton. Note that in real code hardcoding a file path like this is a no-go...

Comment: @MohsenAmiriAmjad I updated my answer, And i removed the static from the field, thanks to @ fabian, I missed that.